# how to get Python logging messages to appear for modules using custom handler

Tags: python, logging, module, handler

I'm trying to use/write a custom Python logging handler. When I use it, logging appears for my main code, but not for a module it uses. I just can't figure how to get the logging for the module `mylib` to appear and would welcome assistance. I'm sure I'm just doing something simple wrong in handling the handler.

The main code of the program is as follows (main.py):

```
import logging
import colorlogging
import mylib

def main():
    global log
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.addHandler(colorlogging.ColorisingStreamHandler())
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.info('started main program')
    mylib.do_something()
    log.debug('main program debug message')
    log.info('finished main program')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The module used by the program is as follows (mylib.py):

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def do_something():
    log.info('doing something')
    log.debug('library debug message')
```

The handler code is as follows (colorlogging.py):

```
import ctypes
import logging
import os

class ColorisingStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):

    # color names to indices
    colorMap = {
        'black':   0,
        'red':     1,
        'green':   2,
        'yellow':  3,
        'blue':    4,
        'magenta': 5,
        'cyan':    6,
        'white':   7,
    }

    # level colour specifications
    # syntax: logging.level: (background color, foreground color, bold)
    levelMap = {
        logging.DEBUG:    (None,   'blue',    False),
        logging.INFO:     (None,   'white',   False),
        logging.WARNING:  (None,   'yellow',  False),
        logging.ERROR:    (None,   'red',     False),
        logging.CRITICAL: ('red',  'white',   True),
    }

    # control sequence introducer
    CSI = '\x1b['

    # normal colours
    reset = '\x1b[0m'

    def istty(self):
        isatty = getattr(self.stream, 'isatty', None)
        return isatty and isatty()

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            message = self.format(record)
            stream = self.stream
            if not self.istty:
                stream.write(message)
            else:
                self.outputColorised(message)
            stream.write(getattr(self, 'terminator', '\n'))
            self.flush()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

    def outputColorised(self, message):
        self.stream.write(message)

    def colorise(self, message, record):
        if record.levelno in self.levelMap:
            backgroundColor, \
            foregroundColor, \
            bold = self.levelMap[record.levelno]
            parameters = []
            if backgroundColor in self.colorMap:
                parameters.append(str(self.colorMap[backgroundColor] + 40))
            if foregroundColor in self.colorMap:
                parameters.append(str(self.colorMap[foregroundColor] + 30))
            if bold:
                parameters.append('1')
            if parameters:
                message = ''.join((
                    self.CSI,
                    ';'.join(parameters),
                    'm',
                    message,
                    self.reset
                ))
        return message

    def format(self, record):
        message = logging.StreamHandler.format(self, record)
        if self.istty:
            # Do not colorise traceback.
            parts = message.split('\n', 1)
            parts[0] = self.colorise(parts[0], record)
            message = '\n'.join(parts)
        return message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `ColorisingStreamHandler` to the root logger so it [will affect all child loggers](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) which propagate the record.

**main.py:**

```
import logging
import colorlogging
import mylib

def main():
    global log
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    root = logging.root
    root.addHandler(colorlogging.ColorisingStreamHandler())
    root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    log.info('started main program')
    mylib.do_something()
    log.debug('main program debug message')
    log.info('finished main program')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yields

```
started main program             (white)
doing something                  (white)
library debug message            (blue)
main program debug message       (blue)
finished main program            (white)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on that! I think I see that you're adding the handler only to the 'topmost' logger. Quick question: Would there be a sensible way of setting the logging level only once? In my non-minimal main program, I am actually setting the logging level using a command line verbosity control. Would the following seem reasonable? ```logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)```

Comment: Indeed, you could set the root logging level instead.